# USB to Windows with MCU/Discrete Chip?

Tags: usb, dac, windows

I've been looking into building a USB DAC for my headphones but I'm struggling to find any info on how USB on windows or MacOS works. I guess I need to know what a chip needs to have in order to be recognized by an OS and, more specifically, how to be recognized as a USB audio device to be able to send audio over it.

My current plan goes DAC --> I2S --> MCU/DSP-->USB-->Computer. I don't know how the MCU/USB/Computer portion would work out.

I haven't been able to find much info about this since I don't know what this would be called and would appreciate any direction.

Thanks!

Comment: While an MCU could be used, why do you think it is necessary? The world is full of USB DAC chips that don't require an MCU.

Comment: Didn't know this. Could you point me to a few? I'm looking 24 or 32Bit and at least 192kHz on the DAC side

Comment: Sorry, asking for suggestions what to buy or from where are off topic. It can't be that hard finding USB codec ICs.

Answer (score 1):

What you're searching for is called a "USB Codec".  These are essentially a single chip with a USB interface and a DAC/ADC.  They typically use the built in Windows/Mac/Android USB driver and will identify as a USB audio device.  I can't recommend a specific one, but Digikey has a page for these with a parametric search, so maybe you can find one with the features you want.

If not, the next option would be to a DAC chip and combine it with a USB interface chip.  This is more complex, but still probably a lot easier than writing your own USB stack on an MCU.

There have been various projects on blogs, github and youtube over the years where people design USB audio devices.  Looking at these may give you ideas as well.